# Lotus script Lockout users

Tags: lotus-domino, lotusscript, lotus

```
Sub Initialize

On Error GoTo e
Dim session As New NotesSession, db As NotesDatabase, view As NotesView
Dim nvec As NotesViewEntryCollection
Dim c As integer
Set db = session.currentdatabase

Set view = db.getView("Locked Out Users")
Set nvec = view.Allentries

c = nvec.count

If c > 0 Then

Call nvec.Removeall(true)

' Send notification
Dim sarr(1) As String
sarr(0) = "john.doe@acme.com"
sarr(1) = "foo@acme.com"

Dim mdoc As NotesDocument, rt As notesrichtextitem
Set mdoc = db.createdocument
mdoc.Form = "Memo"
mdoc.Subject = "Removed " + CStr(c) + " Locked out users on mypage"
Set rt = mdoc.Createrichtextitem("Body")
Call rt.Appendtext("Removed " + CStr(c) + " Locked out users")
Call rt.Addnewline(1) 
Call rt.Appendtext("Click to open lockout database")
Call rt.Appenddoclink(db,"Lockout")
Call mdoc.Send(False, sarr)

End If
Exit Sub
e:
Print Error,erl
End Sub
```

I’m a beginner in Lotus Domino it I have some question , It's possible to change this script to delate only locked users with specified name?

I added something like that:

```
 Dim nam As NotesName
Dim c As integer
Set db = session.currentdatabase
Set nam.OrgUnit1 = (“GD”)
Set view = db.getView("Locked Out Users")
Set nvec.OrgUnit1 = view.Allentries

c = nvec.count

If c > 0 Then
```

In my case I need delete all group person how has specified dc, for example Robert Kowalski/GD/Company everybody how has in name dc=GD?

Comment: FYI  "GD" is not a "dc" in the Lotus world. It is an "Organizational Unit", or "OU".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are at least 2 ways to achieve your request. 
First you can copy the view "Locked Out Users" and change the selection formula to only include your OU.
The other option is something like

```
dim doc as notesdocument
dim nextDoc as notesdocument

set doc = view.getfirstdocument()
while not doc is nothing
 set nextDoc = view.getnextDocument(doc)
 set nam = new notesname(doc.getItemValue("[NAMEITEM]")(0))
 if strcompare(nam.orgUnit1,"GD",5)=0 then
  call doc.remove(true,false)
 end if
set doc = nextDoc 
wend
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Sub Initialize

On Error GoTo e
Dim session As New NotesSession, db As NotesDatabase, view As NotesView
Dim nvec As NotesViewEntryCollection
Dim c As integer
Set db = session.currentdatabase
dim doc as notesdocument
dim nextDoc as notesdocument

set doc = view.getfirstdocument()
while not doc is nothing
 set nextDoc = view.getnextDocument(doc)
 set nam = new notesname(doc.getItemValue("[NAMEITEM]")(0))
 if strcompare(nam.orgUnit1,"GD",5)=0 then
  call doc.remove(true,false)
 end if
set doc = nextDoc 
wend

Set view = db.getView("Locked Out Users")
Set nvec = view.Allentries

c = nvec.count

If c > 0 Then

Call nvec.Removeall(true)

' Send notification
Dim sarr(1) As String
sarr(0) = "john.doe@acme.com"
sarr(1) = "foo@acme.com"

Dim mdoc As NotesDocument, rt As notesrichtextitem
Set mdoc = db.createdocument
mdoc.Form = "Memo"
mdoc.Subject = "Removed " + CStr(c) + " Locked out users on mypage"
Set rt = mdoc.Createrichtextitem("Body")
Call rt.Appendtext("Removed " + CStr(c) + " Locked out users")
Call rt.Addnewline(1) 
Call rt.Appendtext("Click to open lockout database")
Call rt.Appenddoclink(db,"Lockout")
Call mdoc.Send(False, sarr)

End If
Exit Sub
e:
Print Error,erl
End Sub
```

Thank You @umeli for Yours responce. I think now 
it should work.